# multiple routes in single Method controller in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, controller, root

I want to know if it is possible to create multiple roots for single methode controller in laravel? something like this :

```
//route
Route::get('foo/bar', 'FooController@bar');
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', 'FooController@bar');
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}/{date}', 'FooController@bar');

//controller
class FooController extends Controller {

    public function bar($id,$date)
    {
      //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you have to handle null parameters, like that:

```
 public function bar($id=null, $date=null)
 {
      ....
```

But at this point its better to declare e single route with optional parameters:

```
 Route::get('foo/bar/{id?}/{date?}', 'FooController@bar');
```

Comment: thanks @dparoli, its work perfect.. is there are other functions for dealing with such cases ?

Comment: I advice you to read the route section of the docs, keep in mind that every example with a callback should also being applicable to controller actions. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing